# Alphabetical listing group by alphabet in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a member table where I am storing all details about a member including its name, email, phone etc. I want the name will appear as a alphabetical group wise. Such as shown in example.

```
A
  Alan
  Alex
  Amar
  Andy

B
  Bob
  Brad

C
  Calvin
  Clerk
D

E
```

I can sort the field alphabetically using order by  ASC but how do I get them in group of alphabet.

Any suggestions are most welcome. I am using php.

Comment: What groups? Do you want to group them in your database, in an array, in the output? Do you have any code already?

Comment: Issues of data display are often best handled at the application level - e.g. with a simple loop acting on an ordered list.

Comment: Is that application level or presentation level? @Strawberry

Comment: But I want some way to do that

Comment: I have the alphabetical sorted array now how do I display like this in php using only single loop

Comment: @AmarBanerjee - to my mind they're exactly the same thing! :-)

Comment: Will you only be using the 26 standard letters of the English alphabet?

Comment: This question should have the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745091/how-to-display-an-array-under-alphabetical-letters-using-php

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is a bad way to do it, but it can help you now.

```
<?php

    $aGroup = array(
        "A" => array(),
        "B" => array(),
        "C" => array(),
        "D" => array(),
        "E" => array(),
        // until "Z"
        );

    $result = mysql_query("SQL as you want");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $letter = strtoupper($row[0][0]); // I supose that the first column is the name
        $aGroup[$letter][] = $row;
    }

?>
```

Comment: On $letter = strtoupper($row[0][0]); I get the name and the first letter, then I can group it alphabetical. I hope that I helped you!

Comment: I'm not much of a coder but, personally, I think this is a good way!

Comment: It was for keep it simple and easy to read. There are more ways to do it better, but it's a faster way to do it, I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this, within your SQL;

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) as alpha, name from 'user' GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name, 0, 2), name order by 'alpha', 'name'
```

and in php

```
 <?php

    $temp = array(); // would also generate a dynamic array
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 1) as alpha, name from 'user' GROUP BY SUBSTRING(name, 0, 2), name order by 'alpha', 'name'"
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $temp[$row['alpha']][] = $row['name'];
    }

    /* this would create array such as;

    'A'
        --> 'Adam'
        --> 'Apple' 
    'B'
        --> 'Ba...'
        --> 'Be...' 
    */

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This question should have the answer - [How to display an Array under alphabetical letters using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745091/how-to-display-an-array-under-alphabetical-letters-using-php)

Selected answer:

```
$previous = null;
foreach($array as $value) {
    $firstLetter = substr($value, 0, 1);
    if($previous !== $firstLetter) echo "\n".$firstLetter."\n---\n\n";
    $previous = $firstLetter;

    echo $value."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
/* Get the letter user clicked on and assign it a variable called $sort */
$sort = $_REQUEST['letter'];
/* Let's check if variable $sort is empty. If it is we will create a query to display all customers alphabetically ordered by last name. */
if($sort == ""){
$qry= "SELECT * FROM tbl_customers ORDER BY lastname ASC ";
}else{
/* if varible $sort is not empty we will create a query that sorts out the customers by their last name, and order the selected records ascendingly. */
$qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customers WHERE lastname LIKE '$sort%' ORDER BY lastname ASC";
}
/* Notice the use of '%' wilde card in the above query  "LIKE '$sort%'". */
//next step is to execute the query.
$execute = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
/* Before we display results let's create our alphabetical navigation. The easiest way to create the navigation is to use character codes and run them through the "for" loop. */
echo "<p>";
for ($i = 65; $i < 91; $i++) {
printf('<a href="%s?letter=%s">%s</a> | ',
$PHP_SELF, chr($i), chr($i));
}
echo "</p>";
/* now we are ready to display the results. Since out tbl_customers table has only three fileds we will display the results in a paragraphs. In the real world you may need to display the results in a table.
To display the results we will use "do while" loop to fetch the results. If no customers are found we will display an error message. */
if(mysql_num_rows($execute)>0){
do{
echo "<p>" .$result['id']. " " .$result['firstname']. " " .$result['lastname']. "</p>";
}while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute));
}else{
echo "<p>No customer found.</p>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with your select query like this example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `name` ASC ;";
```

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: OP want the group of alphabetic result and `ORDER ASC` return all the collected data not the grouped.

Comment: can you var_dump your result and post it here and i can give you a script.