# Created alphabetical list in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array from mysql query result that I am trying to iterate through and add html around.
The array is ordered alphabetically already but I need to group them by their first letter. How can I go about grouping them and then adding html around it?

This is how the final result should look like:

```
<div class="content js-abc-content">
  <div class="text" data-alpha="a">A</div>
  <ul class="list">
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>A</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="text" data-alpha="b">B</div>
  <ul class="list">
      <li>B</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>B</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is what I have so far...

```
<div class="content">
    <? while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<div class="text" data-alpha="a">A</div>';
        echo '<ul class="list">';
        echo '<li>A</li>';
        echo '<li>A</li>';
        echo '<li>A</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
    } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please show the output of `$row` variable?

Comment: try something like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745091/how-to-display-an-array-under-alphabetical-letters-using-php)

Comment: @TamilSelvanC $row is the row from the mysql query... so $row['name'] would print for example "A"

Comment: Do you want to show the heading letter even if there are no rows for that letter?  We don't quite have a [mcve] yet.

Comment: @mickmackusa no only if rows exist for that letter. I will look at online php editors to create something

Comment: Adding an `id` to the `<ul>` tag will be useful for sending users directly to a section when the url contains an anchor reference. (`yourpage.com#A`)

Comment: various ways to do it https://3v4l.org/LNQqM basically you want to get only the letters you need (from perhaps a query) to loop over, then only loop over them, then pick out data result based on the letter (perhaps a query, or structure your result so you can do [a=>[row,row],b=>[row],c=>row,row,row]), if you loop over the result you cant really backtrack to remove empty, i.e it needs pre-computation before looping else do more querys

Comment: another way, https://3v4l.org/3VVqu