# Group array data by first character and create subarrays in each group

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array something like this:

```
$array = array(
    'Actual Hours' => 'http://www.example.com/actual',
    'Algorithm' => 'http://www.example.com/algorithm',
    'Time Clock App' => 'http://www.example.com/time',
)
```

And I want the output something like this:

```
Array
(
    [A] => [
        [Actual Hours] => http://www.example.com/actual
        [Algorithm] => http://www.example.com/algorithm
    ],
    [T] => [
        [Time Clock App] => http://www.example.com/time        
    ],
    
)
```

So basically I want something like this ..

[image]

As you can see, I want the first letter of the array key and want to sort it by adding a new key and group it that way.

Comment: _"I want..."_ is not an actual question. Have you tried anything? Where _exactly_ are you stuck? You should be able to simply iterate through the array (using `foreach`) and create a new array that looks like you want. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues you have with your code, but this questions reads more like a specification than a question and this isn't a free coding service.

Comment: And first letter is `mb_substr($str, 0, 1)`

Comment: Just use the key instead of the value in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35543688/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go !

```
$array = array(
    'Actual Hours' => 'http://www.example.com/actual',
    'Algorithm' => 'http://www.example.com/algorithm',
    'Time Clock App' => 'http://www.example.com/time',

);

$new_array = [];
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $char = strtoupper(substr($key,0,1));
    if(!array_key_exists( $char, $new_array)) {
        $new_array[$char] = [];
    }
    $new_array[$char][$key] = $value;
}

$array = $new_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop, get the first letter `0` of the key string and add to that with the whole key:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $result[strtoupper($k[0])][$k] = $v;
}
```